# Giving a user super user privileges without access to another user's files

Tags: linux, permissions, administrator

Is it possible to give a user super user privileges but prevent them from accessing another users home directory? I want to allow them to have full control of the system except read permissions to another users files. Obviously, encrypting the other user's home with a passphrase could work, but is there another way to do this by creating a super super user or something, maybe create another partition or special directory that the super user can write to but not read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in linux security model, a root user can basically access any file. And also in Ubuntu you can't login as root graphically, but only in terminal. Other systems support it.

Then if you still give user root priviliges, then the user will have full access to the whole system. The best solution is to move other user's /home partition and encrypt it.